# Is there a programmatic way to create in R create a nested list of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, tibble, echarts

I am new to R, and need to create hierarchical data format in a shiny application, and hence cannot code it manually.
Suppose I have a data frame

```
 parents     labels values
1             Everything     10
2       earth       land     30
3       earth      ocean     30
4        mars     valley     40
5        mars     crater     40
6        land     forest     10
7        land      river     10
8       ocean       kelp     20
9       ocean       fish     20
10       fish      shark     10
11       fish       tuna     10
12 Everything      venus     40
13 Everything      earth     20
14 Everything       mars     30
```

created manually:

```
df <- data.frame(parents = c("","earth", "earth", "mars", "mars", "land", "land", "ocean", "ocean", "fish", "fish", "Everything", "Everything", "Everything"),
                 labels = c("Everything", "land", "ocean", "valley", "crater", "forest", "river", "kelp", "fish", "shark", "tuna", "venus","earth", "mars"),
                 values = c(10, 30, 30, 40, 40, 10, 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 40, 20, 30)
                 )
```

The programatically created tibble nested list should look like this:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  value children        
  <chr> <dbl> <list>          
1 earth    30 <tibble [2 × 3]>
2 mars     40 <tibble [2 × 2]>
3 venus    30 <NULL>
```

I can create it manually like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
    name = c("earth", "mars", "venus"), value = c(30, 40, 30), 
    children = list(
        tibble(name = c("land", "ocean"), value = c(10,20),             # 2nd level
               children = list(
                   tibble(name = c("forest", "river"), value = c(3,7)),   # 3rd level 
                   tibble(name = c("fish", "kelp"), value = c(10,5),
                          children = list(
                              tibble(name = c("shark", "tuna"), value = c(2,6)),  # 4th level 
                              NULL  # kelp
                          ))
               )),
        tibble(name = c("crater", "valley"), value = c(20,20)),
        NULL  # venus
    )
)
```

Manual conversion is not useful to me. Note that I am getting rid of the top layer of 'Everything' , which is fine with me.
Can someone help me convert it to nested tibble list **programmatically**?

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the data shared (input) ? The data shared above (expected output) is not related to data below (input).

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::nest`, e.g. try `tidyr::nest(df, data = -parents)`.

Comment: @RonakShah, I have now edited my ask. Thank you!

Comment: @stefan - nice cursory/glib answer, but no - doesn't work.